# Avoid browser caching after deploy a Vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build

My Vuejs App did not update after deployment for production, every time require "Empty cache and hard reload" to get the updates, I tried a lot of solutions to apply versioning to generated files after build but none of them worked for me, I need a solution to apply new hash for all files after every single build, not just the updated ones.

My `vue.config.js` file content:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/" : "/",
    runtimeCompiler: true,

    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                // If using the runtime only build
                // vue$: "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js" // 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js' for webpack 1
                // Or if using full build of Vue (runtime + compiler)
                vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js', // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
                '@': path.resolve('src'),
                src: path.resolve('src'),
                assets: path.resolve('src/assets'),
                components: path.resolve('src/components'),
                services: path.resolve('src/services'),
            }
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        },
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {

        config.module
            .rule("eslint")
            .use("eslint-loader")
            .tap(options => {
                options.configFile = path.resolve(__dirname, ".eslintrc.js");
                return options;
            });

    },

};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Vue JS cache nightmare. Did you try changing the `version` value in your `package.json`? I use to increment the value on each release as per x.y.z semantinc versioning. Maybe doing something like this:

```js
{
   "name": "My app",
   "version": "1.0.15",
   "private": true,
   ...
}
```